# why is PEAR mimedecode.php body output almost always NULL?

Tags: php, phpmailer, pear, mime, eml

It successfully decodes about 1/20 raw e-mails in .eml format, is it really that rubbish library or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should check the content from the emails that wont work (first debug point). Everthing that you have written after the comma can not evaluated because you show nothing here. How should we know that you are doing something wrong or right?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Sorry I will add a working and non working example right away

Comment: Here are located working and non working .eml file

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sj43cpxfyrl6k5k/AACuHB3vXnZETcBvjZfzHF69a?dl=0

Comment: The not working EMAIL is 3.2 MB in size. Can that be a problem? Its late here have to go, i will have look tomorow.

Comment: I checked the content of emails and tried to find a pattern in working and non working mails but so far nothing that I can put my finger on. Will investigate further...

Comment: Okay I found that PEAR's $variable->body is often NULL and very few times correct body text. But $variable->parts give out array list of bodies in plain text format, html format and even attachments separately every single time. Looks like I'm going to use this instead. Thanks @JustOnUnderMillions for answering though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use parts array output instead of body. Looks like it is more reliable.